# Is there any way to change the name of python when using the terminal

Tags: python

Currently when I need to use python in the terminal or run something with python I need to write "python3 ....."
For example "python3 manage.py makemigrations"
Is there any way I can rename it to something shorter for simplicity like "py"

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can create a symlink in your PATH or alias in your terminal. Do not rename the executable itself...

But some OS prefer you use `python3` since `python` commonly refers to Python 2.x executable, which is end of life, but still exists as a dependency for some programs

Answer (score 0):

If you using Linux or Mac. You can achieve this by using a symbolic link

First, get your python path by using

```
which python
```

Then create a symbolic link

```
ln -s /Users/.virtualenvs/bin/python /Users/.virtualenvs/bin/py
```

Hereafter just using `py` will run as python

Answer (score 0):

Like the first comment, I am also using an alias. However, if you use a dependency manager like [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/), `python` works by default when inside your virtual environment. No need to create an alias.

**Setting up an alias**

1. Open your zshell or bash profile `open ~/.zshrc`
2. Setup your alias in your profile `alias py=/usr/local/bin/python3.9`
3. Save and close the file.
4. Return to your terminal
5. `source ~/.zshrc` (or source your bash profile, whichever setup you
   have)
6. `python`